# Calculate integral with complex numbers over circle

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I want to compute the value of the integral

$$\oint_{C(0,2)} \frac{e^{2 \pi z}-1}{z(z-i)} dz$$

where $C(0,2)$ is the circle with center $0$, radius $2$ and the positive direction of rotation.

It is know that $e^z=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n!}$.

So the integral gets

$$\oint_{C(0,2)} \frac{e^{2 \pi z}-1}{z(z-i)} dz=\oint_{C(0,2)} \frac{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2 \pi z)^n}{n!}-1}{z(z-i)} dz$$

Do we expand further the term to be integraded to get a result? Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Use the residue theorem.

Comment: [This might help](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function extends holomorphically to both $0$ and $i$ and so the integral is $0$ by Cauchy's integral theorem.

Comment: $$\frac{e^{2 \pi z }-1}{z(z-i)}=\frac{\frac{e^{2 \pi z}-1}{z}}{z-i}$$

$$f(z)=\frac{e^{2 \pi z}-1}{z} \text{ singularity at } z=i$$

Then $Res_{z=i} 2 \pi i (f'(z))|_{z=i}=f'(z)= \frac{2 \pi e^{2 \pi z} z -(e^{2 \pi z}-1)}{z^2}$

$$$$

$f'(i)=2 \pi i$.

How do we continue ?

Comment: The singularities are both removable. Check for example $z=0$. **Hint:** The limit as $z$ tends to $0$ is kind of like a derivative.